# SSIS- How to import multiple JSON files in a folder to Oracle?

Tags: json, loops, ssis

I am trying to import multiple JSON files in a folder to an Oracle database using SSIS. The code below is the JSON parser that is able to import a single file. I need this to loop through a folder and import all the files. Here is a the code in the script component to import the JSON file. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\tngo\File\File1.json");

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<IGData> igdatas = js.Deserialize<List<IGData>>(jsonFileContent);

    foreach (IGData igdata in igdatas)

    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.piececount = igdata.piececount;

        Output0Buffer.wgt = igdata.wgt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already in C# you can finish it off there with a foreach loop around your whole code.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\tngo\File\\", "*.json");

foreach(string file in files)
{
    String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(file)
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<IGData> igdatas = js.Deserialize<List<IGData>>(jsonFileContent);

    foreach (IGData igdata in igdatas)

    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.piececount = igdata.piececount;

        Output0Buffer.wgt = igdata.wgt;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would also suggest another column for sourceFile

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `Foreach Loop Task`.

In the Forech Loop Editor do the following:

Use the `Foreach File Enumerator` type and point the Folder to `C:\Users\tngo\File\`. Your Files wildcard will be `*.json`, and you should check `Fully qualified` under `Retrieve file name`. After that, click on `Variable Mapping` on the left pane of the editor, and create a new string variable that will hold you fully qualified filename. We'll call ours `ForEachLoop_StringVar` for this example.

After you create the loop, drag your `Script Task` into the `Foreach Loop`, and then double click the `Script Task` to open the `Script Task Editor`. Add the string variable you created above as a `ReadOnlyVariables`, and then hit the `Edit Script...` button to pull up your script. You can then change the hard-coded filename with a reference to your variable. Your script code would then look something like this:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText((string)Dts.Variables["User::ForEachLoop_StringVar"].Value);

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<IGData> igdatas = js.Deserialize<List<IGData>>(jsonFileContent);

    foreach (IGData igdata in igdatas)

    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.piececount = igdata.piececount;

        Output0Buffer.wgt = igdata.wgt;
    }
}
```